# GORM - dynamic query - Detached Criteria?

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

i have working code like that :

```
def criteria = Instance.createCriteria()
def list = criteria.listDistinct {
    eq("saved", true)
    eq("client", client)

    and {
        basicValues {
            eq("fieldA", object.valueA())
            /** CODE BLOCK **/
        }

        customValues {
            eq("fieldB", object.valueB())
            /** CODE BLOCK **/
        }
    }

    or {
        basicValues {
            eq("fieldC", object.valueC())
            /** CODE BLOCK **/
        }

        customValues {
            eq("fieldD", object.valueD())
            /** CODE BLOCK **/
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, i am creating some criterias with `AND` and `OR` section. In both of them are joined another conditions (basicValues / customValues are in 1:n relationship to Instance). Section /** CODE BLOCK **/ is set of CONDITIONS which are ALWAYS same.

So far i on each `/** CODE BLOCK **/` place put same conditions ( like `lt("field", 10)` etc. ...).

Can i put this `/** CODE BLOCK **/` into function ?. So those conditions would be on one place and code will be much more readable ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make `/** CODE BLOCK**/` into a separate closure, you can include a call to it in your criteria.

```
def commonCriteria = {
    /** CODE BLOCK **/
}

def criteria = Instance.createCriteria()
def list = criteria.listDistinct {
    commonCriteria.delegate = delegate
    eq("saved", true)
    eq("client", client)

    and {
        basicValues {
            eq("fieldA", object.valueA())
            commonCriteria()
        }

        customValues {
            eq("fieldB", object.valueB())
            commonCriteria()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i have tried your solution. in new closure commonCriteria methods like("",""), gt("","") was not know

Comment: @Mato.Duris I left out a line assigning the common criteria delegate, give it another shot if you please.

Comment: hmm ... thats a problem, actually what should i pass there ? like(...), gt(...) are methods inside that closures :-/

Comment: What should you pass where?

Comment: i mean that : "common criteria deletagte" - what kind of object is that ? (not familias with that :-( ) ... next idea is to use DetachedCriteria, i will try use it today

Comment: problem solved ... i just passed delegate as you suggest

Comment: calling of closure : commonCriteria(delegate); in closere just make simple assigment : def commonCriteria = { newDelegate -> deletegate =  newDelegate }

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you could save statements in a closure in pure groovy (*all the `class Deleg` part is to mock your scenario*):

```
class Deleg {
  def invoked = []

  def execute(fn) {
    fn.delegate = this
    fn()
  }

  def and(closure) { execute(closure) }
  def or(closure) { execute(closure) }

  def methodMissing(String method, args) {
    invoked << [method, args]
  }
}

d = new Deleg()

commonOps = { closure -> 
  return {
    closure()
    lower("a")
    upper("b")
  }
}

fn = {
  and commonOps {
    eq("a")
  }

  or commonOps {
    eq("b")
  }
}

d.execute(fn)

assert d.invoked.size() == 6
assert d.invoked == [
  ["eq",    ["a"]],
  ["lower", ["a"]],
  ["upper", ["b"]],
  ["eq",    ["b"]],
  ["lower", ["a"]],
  ["upper", ["b"]],
]
```

I don't know GORM enough, but i think you could do something like that, whereas you'd only need the `commonOps` part. Note it receives and returns a closure.

It works by *returning a closure* which executes the specific statements, passed as a closure parameter, and the generic statements. Note the returned closure is not invoked by your application, but by GORM itself.

Comment: i have tried implement your solution. Code execution goes into "commonOps" but not executed anything inside return { ... }

Comment: It is executed by GORM itself. Maybe you can try putting a `System.out.println()` inside `commonOps` to check if it is getting executed.

Comment: No, it is wrong, you are using two closures. It must be only one, like this: `or commonOps { ... }`, and not `or { commonOps { ... } }`